# Remove approximately Repeated/Duplicate sentences from Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, duplicates, repeat

I am looking for python code that can remove false repetitions occurring in the text.
I want to get rid of all approximately repeated sentences from text.

SAMPLE TEXT IS BELOW **(Bold=false repetitions)**

"**the well well keeping yourself well it can well oh** well keeping yourself clean for time being is a common sense but having couple of hands coming out from your shoulders you can finish everything in a couple of days if you work really hard **but the truth is that but the** but the truth is that preventive actions are often completely useless **now if you remove the cover of your bc now if you if if you remove that** now let me explain"

EXPECTED TEXT OUTPUT

"well keeping yourself clean for time being is a common sense but having couple of hands coming out from your shoulders you can finish everything in a couple of days if you work really hard but the truth is that preventive actions are often completely useless now let me explain"

Comment: *Please suggest Any Better Solutions*. Better than nothing? Please read [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show your efforts. Show the problem you encountered. AND. What is the logic of removing repetition. There is no repetition in *now if you remove the cover of your bc*, so why isn't it in output text? Explain why you delete some and why not others.

Comment: so you want a system that can understand the whole text, and identify blocks of superfluous text that once removed make the text more readable? Looks like you will need a team the size and budget of Google to do that.

Comment: they are just repeating sentences and are basically my repeat takes

Comment: [dedupe is a library that uses machine learning to perform de-duplication and entity resolution quickly on structured data](https://pypi.org/project/dedupe/)